# basic Miktex - QWindowsWindow::setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 451x317+1010+537

Tags: latex, doxygen, pdflatex, miktex

I am running doxygen with LaTeX using basic MikTex (2.9.6850).

On a Windows 7 PC with same version of MikTex, the doxygen output is printed to the PDF as expected and happy days.

But the Windows 10 PC is giving the following error message instead of printing the Doxygen output to the PDF:

```
C:\..\..\..\doc\latex>pdflatex refman
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6840 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(refman.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5

QWindowsWindow::setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 451x317+1010+537 on QWidgetWindow/'InstallPackageDialogWindow'. Resulting geometry:  541x317+1010+537 (frame: 9, 38, 9, 9, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 541x287, maximum size: 16777215x16777215).
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Is it trying to, automatically, install a required package? Do you have the refman.log file? Maybe at the end of the file there is some information of what it tries to do.

Comment: @albert On the Windows 7, yes it tries install automatically, but on the Windows 10 it doesn't. There is no error n the refmon.log

Comment: Are you running the doxywizard ? From where does the error message come (i.e. MikTeX, doxygen, doxywizard)?  If from the Doxywizard can you check what happens when you just run doxygen and start the refman.pdf?

Comment: Partly forget my previous comment, I reread the error message (and some things on the Internet). From the error message it is clearly a MikTeX problem trying to install a package. Not sure what causes it. What you could try is to install the packages beforehand, question will be what will doxygen need? Hard to tell by head (your Windows installation will probably be a bit 'dirty' so not wise to install all packages that you have installed on Windows 7 as well). Maybe best try would be to go to the created 'latex`directory and start the `make` command here.